# make width of <td> equal to its text contents

Tags: html, css

I have below snippet where `td` takes up space unnecessarily. For e.g. if the text contents inside `td` take 20 pixels width, `td` should also be 20 pixels wide. Can you help me fix it?

```css
tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.td2{
   width:auto;
   max-width: 180px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color:red;
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
}

span {
   background-color: #7e7;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="width:600px;">The image in below strucure should be displayed immediately after text ends
but the td is eating up space unnecessarily
</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span>Excessive exhaust materialssss</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span>Excessive</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want the image always to appear right after the text - you probably shouldn't be using a table - because table cells expand according the widest cell in the column

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this code with your old code.

I hop here you find your solution.

```css
tr {
  width: 100%;
  display:table-row;
}
tr td
{
  display:inline-block;
}
.td2{
   width:auto;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color:red;
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   
   max-width: 180px;
}
.text{
  max-width: 180px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
span {
   background-color: #7e7;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="width:600px;">The image in below strucure should be displayed immediately after text ends
but the td is eating up space unnecessarily
</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span class="text">Excessive exhaust materialssss</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span>Excessive</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `max-width` should not be removed. I want to restrict the text width.

Comment: @ScrapCode You want keep `max-width` as it is right?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep max width as it is, but in cases when text takes smaller width, I want `td` as well to take smaller width

Comment: @ScrapCode please check it now and then tell me it's okay or not

Comment: If any changes then tell me

Comment: Hardik, Thanks but it doesn't solve the core problem. I saw that things aren't working for some other text combinations.

Comment: have you seen this code, I have changed. please see this and tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146158/discussion-between-hardik-chapla-and-scrapcode).

Answer (score 1):

By default, table cells will expand in order to fit all their content and the width of the cell will depend on the widest cell in that column.

So trying to shrink-wrap a table-cell doesn't really make much sense.

If you do actually want a table-like layout, but you want a particular column to take up as little space as possible - you could set the cell  `width: 1px;` - that will make the column as wide as the longest word in the cells of that column.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.td2{
   width:auto;
   max-width: 180px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   background-color:red;
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   width: 1px; /* <--- */
}

span {
   background-color: #7e7;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="width:600px;">The image in below strucure should be displayed immediately after text ends
but the td is eating up space unnecessarily
</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span>Excessive exhaust materialssss</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
    <td class="td2"><span>Excessive</span></td>
    <td class="td3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following css code

```
tr {
  width: 100%;
  display:table-row;
}
tr td
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[here is a link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/MowweQ)

hope this helps..

Comment: Doesn't help considering I have `max-width` restrictions.